# outputtext and inputtext editing

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, panelgrid

I have a jsf page and java class:

```
 <p:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2">      
     <h:outputText value="ID:"/>
     <h:outputText value="#{TesztBean.select.id}"/>
     <h:outputText value="Name:"/>
     <h:outputText value="#{TesztBean.select.name}"/>
     <h:outputText value="Age:"/>
     <h:outputText value="#{TesztBean.select.age}"/>
     <h:outputText value="Kapcsolatfelvetel megtortent:"/>                    
     <h:inputText  value="#{TesztBean.select.kapcsolatfelvetel_megtortent}" size="10" rendered="#{TesztBean.canEdit}" />
     <h:outputText value="#{TesztBean.select.kapcsolatfelvetel_megtortent}" rendered="#{not TesztBean.canEdit}" />
     <h:outputText value="Levélküldés dátuma:"/>
     <h:inputText  value="#{TesztBean.select.levelkuldesenek_datuma}" size="10" rendered="#{TesztBean.canEdit}" />
     <h:outputText value="#{TesztBean.select.levelkuldesenek_datuma}" rendered="#{not TesztBean.canEdit}" />
     <h:outputText value="Képzés kezdete:"/>        
     <h:inputText  value="#{TesztBean.select.kepzes_kezdete}" size="10" rendered="#{TesztBean.canEdit}" />
     <h:outputText value="#{TesztBean.select.kepzes_kezdete}" rendered="#{not TesztBean.canEdit}" />
     <h:outputText value="Képzés vege:"/>                    
     <h:inputText  value="#{TesztBean.select.kepzes_vege}" size="10" rendered="#{TesztBean.canEdit}" />
     <h:outputText value="#{TesztBean.select.kepzes_vege}" rendered="#{not TesztBean.canEdit}" />
     <h:commandButton id="commandBena"  value="Edit" actionListener="#{TesztBean.editTeszt}" rendered="#{not TesztBean.canEdit}" />                                                                     
</p:panelGrid>
```

Class:

```
private boolean canEdit = false;;

public boolean isCanEdit() {
    return canEdit;
}

public void setCanEdit(boolean canEdit) {
    this.canEdit = canEdit;
}   

public String getEditTeszt(){
    setCanEdit(true);
    return null;
}
```

[image]

I would like to editing intputtext/outputtext values. when i clicked the edit button,  then i see that in the server log:

> [#|2014-05-19T18:08:42.607+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.faces.event|_ThreadID=74;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.el.MethodNotFoundException:
>   Method not found:
>   hu.educatio.osszesito.teszt.TesztBean@37247706.editTeszt()
>           at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.getMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:160)
>
> javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context|_ThreadID=74;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Method
>   not found: hu.educatio.osszesito.teszt.TesztBean@37247706.editTeszt()
>   javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: Method not found:
>   hu.educatio.osszesito.teszt.TesztBean@37247706.editTeszt()
>           at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:182)

how can i edit outputtext values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is named `getEditTeszt()`, which makes it eligible to be a bean property by convention (with the `get` prefix and a return value). So when you use `"#{TesztBean.editTeszt}"` for you `actionListener`, it's reading it as a property and not a method, as you are leaving out the `get` in the `getEditTeszt`. Hence the exception message `"Method not found"`, as a method is required.

A simple fix would be just to put in the `get` → `"#{TesztBean.getEditTeszt}"`. But in this context, it makes no sense. First of all, your action listener method has no reason to return anything. *Especially* when all you're doing is returning null. You should rather make the method return void. You may be mistaking/missing the difference between `actionListener` and `action`, the latter being the one where you *do* want to return a string, for navigational purposes. Read more at [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909382/2587435)

I would change the name of the method to something else more semantically appropriate. You should avoid using `get` for your method prefix, unless they are actual getters. You've just met one of the reason why.

Comment: I modified the actionlistener:  `<p:commandButton id="commandBena"  value="Edit" actionListener="#{TesztBean.setEditTeszt(event)}" update="growl"/>` and i add a method:  `public void setEditTeszt(ActionEvent event){        
        setCanEdit(true);        
            }` . When i click button, i see in the server log : `canedit is true` but i can not editing inputText/outputText values, Why?   Thank you